# I cant to make 1 Array in PHP with 4 elements but i have 4 arrays with 1 element

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with arrays in PHP.

I need to do the next array:

```
array(
   "Componente 1" => "1",
   "Componente 2" => "2",
   "Componente 3" => "3",
   "Componente 4" => "4",
)
```

and I get this:

```
array(
    array(
      "Componente 1" => "1",
    ),
    array(
      "Componente 2" => "2",
    ),
    array(
      "Componente 3" => "3",
    ),
    array(
      "Componente 4" => "4",
    ),
)
```

My code is

```
$element = array();
foreach ($components as $component)
{
    array_push($element, array($component[0] => $component[1]]);
}
```

and also I had tried with:

```
$element = array();
foreach ($components as $component)
{
    $element[] = array($component[0] => $component[1]]);
}
```

Could you help me.

Thanks very much

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Please include an example of your **expected output**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work:

```
$element = array();
foreach ($components as $component)
{
    $element[$component[0]] = $component[1];
}
```

This is assuming `$components` is an array like `[["Component 1", "1"], ["Component 2", "2"], ... ]`

Comment: Thank very much! that's it!

Comment: No problem! Can you mark this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Just a foreach with one `[]` with key and value you forget to use key in 2nd code and index  `1` in not present

```
 $new=array();
   foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
  $new[] = [$key=>$value];
 }
 print_r($new);
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/858435

Answer (score 0):

make use of array_merge instead of array_push and see what happen